# checkbox jquery-ui not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I use codeigniter with adminre template.

I use the checkbox class "custom-checkbox" that hides the input type="checkbox" and show a box styled with css.

When I trie to pass the focus to that control with the tab key, it doesn't get the focus. 
I think the problem is that the focus goes to the input element and not to the box styled.

If I put the tabindex into the span or div where the checkbox is, it receives the focus but if I press the space key to check it, it doesn't work.

Any idea will be received gratefully!

I hope my explanation is clear enough, the english is not my native language :-(

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your output ?

Comment: Please can you provide jquery code?

Comment: This is the html code  <br/> <div class="checkbox custom-checkbox text-center">      
        <input type="checkbox" style="width:auto;" class="form-control" name="chkField1" value="1" id="chkField1"><label class="control-label" for="obligatorioCampo">&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                        </div>  <br/>The custom-checkbox hides the chkField1 and shows a styled box.